# Compare two variables in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing a script to change passwords on multiple servers. The script accepts username and password as input.

It should ask for password twice and compare if they are equal.

I could not find a way to compare two variables. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
 vars_prompt:
  - name: user_name
    prompt: Enter the user name for password reset
    private: no

  - name: pass
    prompt: Enter the password

  - name: re-pass
    prompt: Re-enter the password

  tasks:

    - name: Verify Password
      debug:
        msg: "Equal"
      when: pass is match re-pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not find a way to compare two varaibles

The thing you want is [`assert:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/assert_module.html), but you will also want to actually name your variable a python-compatible name, else you will have to use the "dict" syntax to access it all the time, which will become annoying:

```
vars_prompt:
- name: pass
- name: re_pass
tasks:
- name: ensure passwords are equal
  assert:
    that:
    - pass == re_pass
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. That worked:)